# What type of connector is this?

Tags: lighting

This connector was removed from my old recessed ceiling lights.  The light socket was wired with this connector at the other end of the lead.  The connector pairs with a female 3-pin/3-hole connector mounted on the socket plate in the recessed light can.   I need to replace a couple of these leads/connectors as they are faulty.  Thanks for any guidance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. My guess is that these are non-standard, and were chosen by the fixture manufacturer for its own reasons. Perhaps now is the time to replace with LEDs...

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to replace with LEDs, however the retrofit LEDs I purchased use an adapter that screws into the existing light socket, however 2 of my sockets aren't working, hence I need to replace the socket and/or socket lead all the way to the socket plate. This connector is on one end of the socket lead...

Answer (score 1):

That is a molex connector, often used in low voltage DC applications. I've seen them in auto/marine lighting applications but never in residential (but that doesn't necessarily mean it's wrong).

Though I question their use in high voltage receptacles the parts are tooling for them are readily available at any electronics retailer.

Comment: Thanks....my understanding is Molex is a brand, and they make many models of connector.  Do you have any idea which this is?

Comment: Molex is regularly used in industrial equipment 120v signal connections and for internal connections in HVAC equipment. There are 2 different pin sizes (diameter), and some are gold plated these are standard tin coated copper pins. A pin removal tool can easily push out the old pins so new ones can be installed if the plastic is still in good shape. There are single pin connectors up to 50 or more. I saw a complete set for 2$ by typing 3 pin Molex connector both male and female pins and shells.